# Indexing vectors with multidimensional arrays

Tags: matlab, indexing

Can someone help me, please?

I have a 4x5x3 matrix and 2x1 column.

```
matrix = ones(4,5,3);
column = ones(2,1);
matrix(1,1,1) = 2;
column(2,1) = 34;
```

When I substitute the values in the matrix using the column all works as expected:

```
column(matrix)

ans(:,:,1) =

34     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1


ans(:,:,2) =

 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1


ans(:,:,3) =

 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
```

In the end I have the same matrix but with substituted values.

However, when I do it like this:

```
matrix = ones(4,5,3);
column = ones(2,2);
matrix(1,1,1) = 2;
column(2,2) = 34;
column(matrix, 2)
ans =

34
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 ...
```

The result doesn't preserves the structure of the original matrix. I want the result to be the same as it was in the previous example, but I want to use the second column for the substitution. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: You could use `reshape` to get the result back into shape.

Comment: @s.bandara, thank you! What solution is more efficient:
1)Use reshape
2)Copy the second column `column_2 = column(:,2); column_2(matrix)`

Comment: I don't know. You should try to profile it if it really matters to you. MATLAB can be surprising in these kind of things.

Comment: @s.bandara, ok I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force dimensions by preallocating the output array:

```
out    = zeros(size(array));
out(:) = column(array, 2)
```

A few timings (assuming you know in advance the size of `array`):

```
sz        = [4,5,3];
array     = ones(sz);
array(1)  = 2;
column    = ones(2);
column(4) = 34;
N         = 1e6;


% extract column
tic
for ii = 1:N
    tmp  = column(:,2);
    out1 = tmp(array);
end
toc

% Preallocate
tic
for ii = 1:N
    out2    = zeros(sz);
    out2(:) = column(array, 2);
end
toc

% Reshape
tic
for ii = 1:N
    out3 = reshape(column(array, 2),sz);
end
toc
```

Results:

```
Extract column: 2.714575 seconds.
Preallocate:    7.179845 seconds.
Reshape:        6.455695 seconds.
```

Also, a note on terminology, a matrix is defined to have two dimensions only.